# Block user when click button in cake php using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

i want to change status in database when click block button. my code is 
Please help me .how should i write query in controller.
my controller function is

```
function blockUser($id="") {
    if(isset($this->request->data['blok'])) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By considering your table as => "Users"
and considering the column as => 'status'

```
$entity=$this->Users->get($id);
$dataToInsert['status']='blocked';
$updateEntity=$this->Users->patchEntity($entity, $dataToInsert);
if($this->Users->save($updateEntity)){
$this->Flash->success(__('User details saved.'));

} else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('Error in saving user details'));
    }
```

This will help you :)

Comment: By default my table field status is 1. and status define 0:block and 1:unblock and i have get id used ajax. My question is that.

Comment: If you are sending request through post or get, use $this->request->data in controller to get the id. @Deepak